# Boas práticas MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Estou iniciando agora um projeto um tanto quanto grande, e optei por utilizar a estrutura MVC.

Criei toda a base do backoffice em uma pasta, porém ao cria-la me veio a seguinte dúvida: Devo criar uma outra estrutura (ou copiar a atual) na raiz para o front do sistema? Ou dentro de cada pasta (models, views, controllers) devo criar uma pasta para o back e outra para o front?

Como o MVC serve para manter um sistema organizado e com aproveitamento de classes, não vi vantagem em criar duas estruturas, então gostaria de saber a melhor prática relacionada a isso.

Comment: Diego, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Se possível poderia [edit] sua pergunta e incluir a estrutura que você criou/deseja criar? Fiquei um pouco confuso e não entendi bem sua ideia.

Comment: Ao ler o segundo parágrafo já npercebi a confusão. Se chegou nesse ponto, com certeza tem problema lógico. A minha pegunta é, o que vc realmente entende de MVC? Se puder descrever resumidamente o que vc entende sobre MVC, podemos então ter um ponto de partida.

Comment: Amigos, eu mesmo percebi minha confusão lógica, rs. Como nunca utilizei o MVC antes estava preso as três pastas padrão. Porém resolvi o seguinte, dentro de controllers e models vou criar duas pastas, admin e front. Vou criar na raiz uma pasta para as views do admin e outra para as views do front. Assim resolve meu problema, pois antes pensava que para seguir os padrões teria que misturar os arquivos do admin com os do front para não fugir das três pastas padrão. Desculpem a confusão.

Answer (score 2):

Fala Diego,
segue uma dica de como você pode organizar seus sistema:

- Admin

  - resources
  - controllers
  - models
  - views
- Portal ( Front )

  - resources
  - controllers
  - models
  - views

Já trabalhei em alguns projetos, que utilizam essa estrutura e foi bem prático.
Para você ter uma base de qual estrutura adotar, vale dar um confere em como os frameworks do mercados estão fazendo isso.

A estrutura acima é parecida com a do CakePHP.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html

Comment: É exatamente dessa forma que estou fazendo. Tive que fazer uma adaptação na classe principal, pois por padrão ela acessa os controllers da raiz. Pra abrir o admin precisei identificar pela url, aí sim a classe sabe qual pasta controller é pra acessar. Não consegui pensar em algo diferente ainda para identificar se é pra abrir as pastas do admin ou front, mas nesse meu método funciona. Se tiver algum melhor será de grande valia, pois ainda estou no início e qualquer modificação é tranquila por enquanto.