# Exibir e editar dados cadastrados

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Criei um sistema de cadastro e queria saber como faço para que as informações que foram cadastradas sejam exibidas na página e que o usuário possa edita-las. Segue meu código abaixo.

```
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
<label><br />
    Nome:
</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Primeiro Nome" />
<label><br />
    Sobrenome:
</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Segundo Nome" />
<label><br />
    Email:
</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email@hotmail.com.br" />
<label><br />
    Senha:
</label><br />
    <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="********" />
<label><br />
    Confirmar Senha:
</label><br />
    <input type="password" name="csenha" placeholder="********" /><br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="button" />
        <input type="reset" name="Redefinir" value="resetar"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["button"])) {
        $nome       = $_POST["nome"];
        $sobrenome  = $_POST["sobrenome"];
        $email      = $_POST["email"];
        $senha      = $_POST["senha"];
        $csenha     = $_POST["csenha"];

        if($nome == "" || $sobrenome == "" || $email == "" || $senha == "" || $csenha == "") {
            echo "<script> alert('Preencha todos os campos!'); </script>";
            return true;
        }
        if ($senha != $csenha) {
            echo "<script> alert ('As senhas devem ser iguais!'); </script>";
            return true;
        }   

        $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Email='$email'");
        if($select) {
        $row = $select->num_rows;
        if($row > 0) {
            echo "<script> alert ('Já existe um usuário com esse e-mail'); </script>";
        } else {
            $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`nome`, `sobrenome`, `email`, `senha`) VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha')");
        if($insert) {
            echo "<script> alert ('Usuário registrado com sucesso!'); location.href='cadastrou.php' </script>";
        }   else {
                echo $mysqli->error;
            }   
        }
    }   else{
    echo $mysqli->error;

    }   

}       
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com base no seu `SELECT` da pra ver que você utiliza o campo `email` como identificador de cada usuário, então seu `UPDATE` vai ser muito parecido como o `INSERT` e o único detalhe é o `WHERE email = $email`.

```
if($row > 0) {
    $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `usuarios` 
                              SET `nome` = '$nome', 
                                  `sobrenome` = '$sobrenome',
                                  `senha` = $senha
                              WHERE `email` = $email");
} else {
    $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`nome`, `sobrenome`, `email`, `senha`) VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha')");
if($insert) {
    echo "<script> alert ('Usuário registrado com sucesso!'); location.href='cadastrou.php' </script>";
} elseif ($update) {
    cho "<script> alert ('Usuário atualizado com sucesso!'); location.href='atualizou.php' </script>";
} else {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

Só que esse código possui **2 grandes problemas**:

1. A concatenação de parâmetros na `query` causa falhas de segurança, um exemplo disso, é que vai permitir qualquer usuário executar um [`SQL Injection`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php).
2. Sua tela não valida o usuário, caso algum usuário que não seja o `administrador` entrar nessa tela ele consegue alterar a senha de qualquer usuário.

### Solução do problema #1

Passar os parâmetros através do [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

```
$sql = "UPDATE `usuarios` 
        SET `nome` = ?, 
            `sobrenome` = ?,
            `senha` = ?
         WHERE `email` = ?";


$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

/* s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $nome, $sobrenome, $senha, $email);

$stmt->execute();

if (!$stmt->errno)
    echo 'Atualizado {$stmt->affected_rows} registros';
```

-

### Solução do problema #2

Da mesma forma que você valida os campos se estão preenchidos ou não, você poderia validar se o usuário logado da `$_SESSION` é um usuário que possui esses privilégios.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, ajudou bastante ! Já marquei como certa

Answer (score 4):

#### Como Fazer

Pra possibilitar a edição você precisa de uma variável para selecionar o usuário e deixar os dados dele no form. Antes de tudo pegue todo o seu código PHP e coloque antes do código HTML.

Agora inicie as variáveis que vão no *Form HTML*:

```
$codigo = '';
$nome = '';
$sobrenome = '';
$email = '';
```

Insira no formulário um campo para o código do usuário

```
<input type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?=$codigo?>">
```

<sub>Não esqueça de passar as demais variáveis nos atributos `value` dos outros campos.</sub>

Receba esse campo no *POST*:

```
$codigo     = filter_var($_POST["codigo"], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Agora quando verificamos se existe um usuário no banco, precisamos também verificar se é um novo ou edição, isso pode ser feito verificando o código:

```
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Email='$email'");
if($select) {
    $row = $select->num_rows;
    $f = $select->fetch_assoc(); // Popula os dados na variável
                   // Verifica se o código é diferênte (se for novo usuário ou outro irá funcionar para ambos)
    if($row > 0 && $codigo !== intval($f['id'])) {
        echo "<script> alert ('Já existe um usuário com esse e-mail'); </script>";
```

No *statement* de insert, precisamos verificar se é novo ou update, se for novo pegar o ID:

```
if (empty($codigo)) { // Verifica se é novo
    $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`nome`, `sobrenome`, `email`, `senha`) VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha')");
    if($insert) {
        $codigo = $mysqli->insert_id; // Pega o id gerado
        echo "<script> alert ('Usuário registrado com sucesso!'); location.href='cadastrou.php' </script>";
```

E por último, gerar o *UPDATE*:

```
} else {
    $sql  = "UPDATE `usuarios` SET 
                `nome` = '$nome', 
                `sobrenome` = '$sobrenome', 
                `email` = '$email', 
                `senha` = '$senha' 
            WHERE
                `id` = $codigo";
    $update = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if($update) {
        echo "<script> alert ('Usuário atualizado com sucesso!'); location.href='cadastrou.php' </script>";
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }
}
```

Para buscar os dados de um usuário você pode fazer utilizando GET:

```
if (!empty($_GET['codigo']) && filter_var($_GET['codigo'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
    $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Email='$email'");
    if($select) {
        $row = $select->num_rows;
        $f = $select->fetch_assoc();
        if($row > 0) {
            $codigo     = $f['codigo'];
            $nome       = $f['nome'];
            $sobrenome  = $f['sobrenome'];
            $email      = $f['email'];
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>O exemplo acima funciona da seguinte forma: `http://localhost/cadastro.php?codigo=1`</sub>

---

#### Código Completo

```
<?php
    $codigo = '';
    $nome = '';
    $sobrenome = '';
    $email = '';
    if(isset($_POST["button"])) {
        $codigo     = filter_var($_POST["codigo"], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        $nome       = filter_var($_POST["nome"]);
        $sobrenome  = filter_var($_POST["sobrenome"]);
        $email      = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        $senha      = $_POST["senha"]; // Considere criptografar a senha antes de inserir no banco
        $csenha     = $_POST["csenha"];


        if ($email === false){
            echo "<script> alert('E-mail inválido!'); </script>";
            return true;
        }

        if($nome == "" || $sobrenome == "" || $email == "" ||  (empty($codigo) && ($senha == "" || $csenha == ""))) {
            echo "<script> alert('Preencha todos os campos!'); </script>";
            return true;
        }
        if ($senha != $csenha) {
            echo "<script> alert ('As senhas devem ser iguais!'); </script>";
            return true;
        }

        $erro = false;

        $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Email='$email'");
        if($select) {
            $row = $select->num_rows;
            $f = $select->fetch_assoc();
            if($row > 0 && $codigo !== intval($f['codigo'])) {
                echo "<script> alert ('Já existe um usuário com esse e-mail'); </script>";
                $erro = true;
            } else {

                if (empty($codigo)) {
                    $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`nome`, `sobrenome`, `email`, `senha`) VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha')");
                    if($insert) {
                        $codigo = $mysqli->insert_id;
                        if(empty($_GET['codigo'])) $_GET['codigo'] = $codigo;
                        echo "<script> alert ('Usuário registrado com sucesso!'); location.href='cadastrou.php' </script>";
                    } else {
                        $erro = true;
                        echo $mysqli->error;
                    }
                } else {
                    $sql  = "UPDATE `usuarios` SET 
                                `nome` = '$nome', 
                                `sobrenome` = '$sobrenome', 
                                `email` = '$email', 
                                `senha` = '$senha' 
                            WHERE
                                `codigo` = $codigo";
                    $update = $mysqli->query($sql);
                    if($update) {
                        echo "<script> alert ('Usuário atualizado com sucesso!'); location.href='cadastrou.php' </script>";
                    } else {
                        $erro = true;
                        echo $mysqli->error;
                    }
                }

            }
        } else {
            $erro = true;
            echo $mysqli->error;
        }

        if ($erro){
            $codigo     = '';
            $nome       = '';
            $sobrenome  = '';
            $email      = '';
            $senha      = '';
            $csenha     = '';
        }
    }


    if (!empty($_GET['codigo']) && filter_var($_GET['codigo'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
        $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Email='$email'");
        if($select) {
            $row = $select->num_rows;
            $f = $select->fetch_assoc();
            if($row > 0) {
                $codigo     = $f['codigo'];
                $nome       = $f['nome'];
                $sobrenome  = $f['sobrenome'];
                $email      = $f['email'];
            }
        }
    }
?>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?=$codigo?>">
    <label><br />
        Nome:
    </label><br />
    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Primeiro Nome" value="<?=$nome?>" />
    <label><br />
        Sobrenome:
    </label><br />
        <input type="text" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Segundo Nome" value="<?=$sobrenome?>" />
    <label><br />
        Email:
    </label><br />
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email@hotmail.com.br" value="<?=$email?>" />
    <label><br />
        Senha:
    </label><br />
        <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="********" />
    <label><br />
        Confirmar Senha:
    </label><br />
    <input type="password" name="csenha" placeholder="********" /><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="button" />
    <input type="reset" name="Redefinir" value="editar"/>
</form>
</body>
```

---

#### Considerações

Considere criptografar sua senha, estude sobre em:

1. [Criptografar senha e se logar PHP e PDO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45287/criptografar-senha-e-se-logar-php-e-pdo)
2. [Qual a melhor maneira de criar um sistema de login com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-o-melhor-jeito-de-fazer-um-sistema-de-login-em-senha-com-php)

Considere utilizar uma biblioteca para gerenciar sua conexão:

1. https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionMSi

Considere separar seu código de cadastro da página de cadastro, leia mais em:

1. [Como implementar o padrão MVC em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63511/como-implementar-o-padr%C3%A3o-mvc-em-php/63513#63513)
2. [Boas práticas MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63890/boas-pr%C3%A1ticas-mvc)

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, mas o meu problema já foi solucionado. :)

Comment: Tranquilo @RuanRodrigues, obrigado pela pergunta.

Comment: Desconhecia esse `filter_var` e interessante as considerações :D

Comment: Sua resposta ajudou bastante também ^^